# ¿Una clase se registra como tipo antes de definir sus atributos y por eso puede tener un tipo de la misma clase como atributo?

Tags: java

¿Una clase se registra como un tipo antes de definir sus atributos y por eso puede tener un tipo de la misma clase como atributo?

Esto significa que primero se registra la clase y posteriormente se le registran los campos que van a tener asociados los objetos de esta?

```
class Persona{
    private Persona persona;
    private Persona2 atributo_persona2;

}

class Persona2{
   private String atributo;
}
```

Puedo tener una clase declarada abajo y sin embargo puedo declarar un objeto de esta como atributo en la clase de arriba

¿Como hace Java para resolver esto? ¿Registra la clase de arriba y luego asigna los atributos menos el que es objeto de la clase de abajo? y mientras tanto sigue compilando el código para ver ver si hay una clase con ese nombre para posteriormente registrarla y ahora si dejar registrado como atributo un objeto de esa clase en la clase que declare arriba?

Comment: En general los compiladores hacen varias pasadas al codigo porque no hay un orden de compilacion en particular. Entonces se resuelven cosas y referencias en cada pasada a medida que van apareciendo...

Answer (score 2):

Este tipo de comportamiento es normal. De hecho en la API puedes encontrar casos así, como es el caso de LinkedList.Node:

```java
private static class Node<E> {
    E item;
    LinkedList.Node<E> next;
    LinkedList.Node<E> prev;

    Node(LinkedList.Node<E> prev, E element, LinkedList.Node<E> next) {
        this.item = element;
        this.next = next;
        this.prev = prev;
    }
}
```

Fíjate que lo que no ocurre es que se referencie a sí mismo en el constructor, es decir, lo que sí está prohibido es:

```java
public class Stub {
    private Stub stub;

    public Stub(Stub stub) {
        this.stub = this;
    }
}
```

Te saltaría un `StackOverflow`.

Answer (score 1):

En el caso planteado se permite esa sintaxis ya que java, en tiempo de compilación, reconoce el tipo de dato puesto como atributo de la clase. Será en tiempo de ejecución y al momento de instanciar ese atributo  `private Persona persona = new Persona();` en donde te encontrarás con un `StackOverFlowError`.